Bad 1980s movie about world class thieves challenged to steal ____, what was the movie?
First, forgive me. I am attempting to recall a movie I only saw once decades ago when I was in middle school.
Basic plot was some rich guy challenges all the world class thieves to steal his diamond, jewelry, gold crown, or something portable at least. Booby traps are set about the place. Some thieves die.
In the end, some amateur thief manages to steal successfully. He disguised himself in a black & white checker pattern spandex body suit that matched the background walls. He was able to sneak around the room undetected.
That is all I remember.
It was B-movie. If there were any future or current famous actors, then I would not know. Looked like could have been made in the late 1970s.
If it helps, then let you know I saw the movie on broadcast syndicated channel in the summer of '83 or '84.

Flexing my google-fu turned up a question from several years ago that matches the details in this question.  Gilles Tran commented that the plot matches Shalimar (1978) and the person who posed the question agreed.  Question text:-

...It involves a "master thief" who keeps a priceless jewel at his
  estate and has it protected by all sorts of elaborate booby-traps. He
  invites other great thieves from around the world to try to steal it.
  They all try and fail (and die) except one. I only clearly remember
  the end. The jewel is kept in a room with a black-and-white
  checkerboard floor, which is mined and observed over CCTV. The last
  remaining thief dons a black-and-white body suit to blend in with the
  floor and has a small hald-held mine detector. He slowly crawls along
  the floor, sweeping for mines as he goes. The master thief sees him on
  the monitor at the last minute because the squares on his outfit don't
  line up with the checkboard pattern on the floor. I can't remember if
  the thief gets away.

IMDb Plot summary:-

On the run from the police, S.S. Kumar, a thief, comes across a
  private invitation to the island of Sir John Locksley addressed to
  Raja Bahadur Singh. When the Raja is shot, Kumar takes him to a nearby
  hospital, dons a Sikh's turban, poses as the Raja's son and goes to
  the private island of John. Also attending are K.P.W. Iyengar, Dr.
  Bukhari, Colonel Columbus, and Countess Rasmussen. A stunned Kumar
  finds out that all of these invitees are master criminals and
  gangsters. Kumar's guise does not fool anyone, including his former
  sweetheart, Sheila Enders, nevertheless John permits him to stay on,
  as he feels that Kumar's career, though an amateur, is consistent with
  those already present. The reason why John has invited them is to find
  a successor to take his place as he is dying of cancer. He feels that
  one of his invitees can be trusted to take his place and for this he
  has arranged for them to steal a diamond (Shalimar) worth 135 crores
  of rupees. This gem is placed in a secure place within his palace,
  which is alarmed, and guarded by armed men 24 hours a day. He
  challenges one of them to steal the shalimar - but if anyone fails
  then they are killed instantly. Pitted against such veterans, it looks
  like Kumar has got himself into a bind that he may not come out of in
  one piece.

The YouTube contains a full copy, and the scene in question can be viewed here
